# How to store a list of weekdays in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm writing an application using **PHP** and I need to store a list of unique weekdays in **MySQL**.

In the application, I have an array to store the weekdays, like this:

```
$days = [
    'Wed',
    'Thu',
    'Sat',
];
```

I know I can use a `SET` column, but I prefer to not use this type due incompatibility with the framework I'm using (Laravel).

How can I save this list using a format that I can still search within the stored values? I'd like to retrieve all rows that have a Sunday, for instance.

Comment: normalize. - put the values into a child table, then link with an FK, e.g. mon =1, tue = 2,... sun=7. then you can either search by the raw values, or join the child table and search by the symbolic name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To solve this problem, I end up using a bitmask to store the weekdays.

I changed the weekdays array contents to something like this:

```
$days = [
     8, // Wednesday
    16, // Thursday
    64, // Saturday
];
```

Using this list as reference:

```
 1 : Sunday
 2 : Monday
 4 : Tuesday
 8 : Wednesday
16 : Thursday
32 : Friday
64 : Saturday
```

Then I added a `TINYINT` column to hold the weekdays bitmask. When storing the values in the database I can simply use the following:

```
$valueToMySQL = array_sum($days); // 88, with the sample above
```

To search for rows with a specific weekday, Saturday for example, I can use this condition:

```
... WHERE `weekdays` & 64;
```

Retrieve the weekdays from database as an array is a little less simple. I'm using the following logic:

```
$days = [];
$bitmask = strrev(decbin($valueFromMySQL));
for ($i = 0, $s = strlen($bitmask); $i < $s; $i++) {
    if ($bitmask{$i}) {
        $days[] = pow(2, $i);
    }
}
```

If I need to retrieve all rows with the same weekday as the current date, I can pass the current weekday to the previous SQL condition as follows:

```
$weekday = (int) date('w'); // 0 for Sunday, to 6 for Saturday
$weekdayToMySQL = pow(2, $weekday); // 1 - 64
```

Then:

```
... WHERE `weekdays` & {$weekdayToMySQL};
```

Comment: That's a neat trick, but how is it better/easier/faster than just using explode and implode (or serialize, json_encode/decode) and then using LIKE to query?

Comment: @Adelphia, starting with the PHP side, `array_sum` is faster than `implode`, `serialize` and `json_encode`, at least for the number of items I'm using in this case. But, it's only a matter of nanoseconds. In the MySQL side, maybe if the data was JSON encoded or serialized, it'll be easy to use `LIKE '%"Thu"%'`, for instance. But if you have a simple list of values joined with commas, you maybe have to use more than one `LIKE` condition with `OR`. If you need to match two or more weekdays, you'll invariably end up using more than one `LIKE` with `AND`.

Comment: Another benefit of having the data stored as an integer, is that you always be sure of the kind of data. I think I have more control over an integer than a string. But it's just my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I used mysql's `WEEKDAY()` function, by passing `WEEKDAY(CURDATE())` i get the weekday number.

> Note: 0 = Monday, 1 = Tuesday, 2 = Wednesday, 3 = Thursday, 4 =
>   Friday, 5 = Saturday, 6 = Sunday.

```
SELECT WEEKDAY("2019-01-28");
```

This would return 0

I stored data as comma separated in my table field, and find it by using `IN` clause

> table_data

```
q_id | weekdays
 1   |   0,1   
 2   |   0,1,2
 3   |   0,2,4
 4   |   1,2,3,4
```

> Below is query which will return records containing current week day number.

```
 SELECT `q_id` FROM table_data WHERE WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) IN (weekdays);
```

> **Edit**

As Gustavo pointed out in comments this above does not work in mysql 5.7  For that `DAYOFWEEK()` works but week numbers are different than above example, you can find documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek).

Comment: If I try to use `IN` operator with a string, it throws a syntax error. E.g. `SELECT 'x' IN 'a,b,c';` doesn't work, however, `SELECT 'x' IN ('a','b','c');` does. Are you exploding/splitting your comma separated string before using it with `IN`?

Comment: no because i am storing comma separated value in record, so i just pass the column name.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still couldn't find any resource pointing to the availability of `IN` operator with comma-separated strings (`VARCHAR`, `TEXT`, ...). I also wasn't able to make it work on my current MySQL setup. I'm using 5.7.

Comment: You are right, I have updated my answer, please fill free to update if any context is missing or wrong.