# How to get all the days of the month

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get a list of days of a given month , let's say the user enters the month 12
the result should be like this :

```
______________
| Tuesday     |
|_____________|
| Wednesday   |
|_____________|
| Thursday    |
 .
 .
 .
```

till the last day of that month, and as for the year depends on the current year.

Comment: http://php.net/date

Comment: How ill you know that Wednesday referers to 9th december, and not to 16th december?

Comment: show what you tried to create. If you have 'no clue', please read this first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32617522/how-to-store-a-list-of-weekdays-in-mysql

Comment: Note that sql is for the storage and retreival of relational data, and not much else.

Comment: PHP would be able to do this. Do you need it in SQL?

Comment: create 2 dates (start of month, end of month), while startDate <= endDate, output the day of the week, add 1 day to startDate

Comment: Confused as to why this was closed - the question was very clear. Just because you don't know what they intend to do with it doesn't make what was actually requested unclear.

Comment: No, the question is still very unclear. (to me, and to at least 2 other people) 

Comment: @Popnoodles: if you do this in SQL, you can also use the results (if more than just daynames are returned) in other queries like i.e. monthly reports.  (see: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614739/how-to-get-data-back-from-mysql-for-days-that-have-no-statistics) )

Answer (score 1):

For the `with recursive`, MySQL 8 is needed":

```
with recursive cte as (
   select cast(DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 1-DAYOFMONTH(curdate()) DAY) as date) as d
   union all 
   select date_add(d, interval 1 day) 
   from cte 
   where month(date_add(d, interval 1 day))=MONTH(curdate())) 
select dayname(d) Days from cte;
```

output:

```
+ ------------------- +
| Days                |
+ ------------------- +
| Tuesday             |
| Wednesday           |
| Thursday            |
| Friday              |
| Saturday            |
| Sunday              |
| Monday              |
| Tuesday             |
| Wednesday           |
| Thursday            |
| Friday              |
| Saturday            |
| Sunday              |
| Monday              |
| Tuesday             |
| Wednesday           |
| Thursday            |
| Friday              |
| Saturday            |
| Sunday              |
| Monday              |
| Tuesday             |
| Wednesday           |
| Thursday            |
| Friday              |
| Saturday            |
| Sunday              |
| Monday              |
| Tuesday             |
| Wednesday           |
| Thursday            |
+ ------------------- +
31 rows
```

EDIT: Changed to list the day for current month.

Comment: "and as for the year depends on the current year" - is it possible to extract the current year from SQL without writing 2020?

Comment: But the years needs to be something variant let's say the users enters 12 in the year 2030 then the result will be different I need some query that uses CURRENTDATE function

Comment: I made the change to get the list for the `CURDATE()`   This code can be changed pretty simple to make a stored procedure with 2 paramaters, year and month.  With that change you can get the days for every month you whish.